# Why it doesn’t always rain with lightning and thunder when it’s hot

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting, thunderstorm

Thunderstorms happen after a period of warm weather. There are times though in the summer after it’s been warm for a while and even after it was 95 degrees Fahrenheit, the thunderstorms they predicted just ends up being rain without lightning and thunder even when it was hot outside. Why is this?

Comment: @Fred it is the exact question asked differently. To have lightning you need to have cumulonimbus clouds. OP does not specify what kind of clouds it is. Could be nimbo stratus as well. Now within that cumulonimbus cloud the vertical velocity of an air parcel needs to be have of a certain magnitude as explained in the linked answer.

Comment: Read the question carefully it is not a duplicate. There is no question the same as mine on this site

Comment: I’m not asking which clouds produce lightning and thunder I’m asking why that thunderstorms and thunderclouds usually form when it is warm weather but there are times where it is hot and even 90 degrees outside but it just ends up being rain without any thunder or lightning even though thunderstorms were in the forecast